# Laravel Mix: These dependencies were not found:

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I have a fresh install of Laravel 5.4. I as well have the folowing versions installed on my Windows PC
node: 6.11.0
npm:5.0.3

I have already run npm install, however, when i run npm run watch, i get the following error

```
> @ watch C:\xampp\htdocs\tu
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
Webpack is watching the files…
                                                                                                                                95% emitting

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                             12:12:42 AM

These dependencies were not found:

* C:\xampp\htdocs\tu\resources\assets\js\app.js in multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
* C:\xampp\htdocs\tu\resources\assets\sass\app.scss in multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

To install them, you can run: npm install --save C:\xampp\htdocs\tu\resources\assets\js\app.js C:\xampp\htdocs\tu\resources\assets\sass\app.scss
```

I've searched the internet but cant seem to get it working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are those dependencies there? Have you ran npm install --save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to revert to this package.json. You can find it here:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c1643bf0c59b6864fc55e09cce3bfafc67d29e2a/package.json

And try to run it again, also make sure, there's a `node_modules/moment` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the respose. Doing the aabove gives me the error `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tu\$npm_package_config_webpack'`

Comment: @ahabsy create the laravel project again; the run npm install. then npm run dev and finally npm run watch . NOTE MAKE SURE U HAVE NODE JS INSTALLED BEFORE DOING THE STEPS

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue but this solution didn't work for me. I guess it's related to my node or npm installation somehow. It doesn't work even when trying to compile the assets for a brand new Laravel project. I have node 8.1.3 and npm 5.2.0.

Comment: NVM, just found it's indeed related to NPM: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/990

Answer (score 5):

I was having the exact same issue but [Leo_Kelmendi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44866108/1128918) didn't work for me.

Searching on GitHub, I found there is a bug in NPM 5.2.0 that affects Laravel Mix. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/990).

I had to revert NPM to its previous version in order to get my assets compiling again:

```
$ sudo npm install -g npm@5.1.0
```

Then, I removed all installed modules:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm cache clear --force
$ rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Notice that clearing the cache may take a while.

And, finally, I reinstalled node deps and run the `dev` script:

```
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```